Connection Refused Errors During Pod Startup on Karpenter-Managed Nodes
In EKS clusters using Karpenter for node provisioning, pods experience temporary "connection refused" errors during initial startup phase. The issue manifests as failed readiness and liveness probe checks, typically lasting for the first ~60 seconds after pod creation.
Symptoms:

Pods initially report "connection refused" errors for health checks

After approximately 1 minute, pods become healthy without intervention

This occurs consistently on:

Newly provisioned Karpenter nodes

New pods scheduled to existing Karpenter nodes

Error pattern:
Warning  Unhealthy  43s   kubelet    Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.12.10:8000/v1/health":
dial tcp 10.0.12.10:8000: connect: connection refused
Warning  Unhealthy  43s   kubelet    Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.0.12.10:8000/v1/health":
dial tcp 10.0.12.10:8000: connect: connection refused


Key Characteristics:

Issue is specific to Karpenter-managed clusters
Not observed in clusters using Cluster Autoscaler
Affects application health checks during initial pod startup
Self-resolves after initial startup period
May impact application availability during scaling events


EKS version: 1.29
Karpenter version: 0.37.0
VPC CNI Plugin: v1.16.0-eksbuild.1



can you provide your config file ?
